# Accents in no english languages (greek, spanish...) in ubuntu 14.04 and wine (or similar) (e.g. MSOffice)

Tags: 14.04, wine, crossover

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 and in this version I have a problem. It is that when I write a vocal with accent (e.g. a + ´ = á) nothing is written. nothing is nothing (no a without accent or ´a)

I have report this error in [codewaeavers](http://www.codeweavers.com/support/forums/general/?t=26;msg=163070) (Crossover):

> Hello
>
> I'm using Crossover 12.5.1 and ubuntu 14.04, and I have installed MSOffice 2010.
>
> When I write accents (e.g. é) nothing is written in the text. Nothing is nothing (e + ' = no string).
>
> I used Crossover in ubuntu 13.10 and I didn't have problems. but in this versions, (in two different ubuntu installations) I have it.
>
> Which can be the problem?
>
> Thanks
>
> EDIT: My last attempt has been with a empty ubuntu

And I have seen other persons with the same problem [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218032)

Does anybody knows a solution or if is the problem being solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution has been posted in codeweavers, it is disable IBUS on system configuration.  Set the default input method from System Settings >> Language Support >> Default input method.

NOTE: You need restart the pc

Answer (score 1):

Open playonlinux and select the Word shortcut, then click configure. Go to the 'Miscellaneous' tab, and in the 'Command to exec before run' textbox, enter: 
XMODIFIERS=""
Keep the keyboard entry method on IBus. 
Repeat for other office apps links. 
it works on ubuntu 16.04 also.

Answer (score 0):

For greek accents what works for me is to add a greek keyboard and switch to it when I need to write in Greek. To accent a character then use

```
; followed by letter to be accented.
```

Answer (score -1):

Install (with apt-get) and use **lxkeymap** command.

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved and perhaps accepted if you were to include instructions that a newb could follow without further guidance.

Comment: Not work :( because lxkeymap only change between keyboard distribution and I have the correct keyboard distribution, my problem. Thanks anyway